# What is the sound of this instrument/synth?

Tags: guitar-effects, midi-controller-keyboard

I am trying to create a song using a specific sound from a song, but can't figure out what is creating the sound. I have it narrowed down to either a guitar or a synth/keyboard, but can't figure out how they are modulating to achieve the effect.
The song in question is

"Nikushimi wo Koete" by Sahashi Toshihiko.